# Is the exceptfds fd_set only used for monitoring OOB data and failed connect attempts in WinSock?

Tags: c++, winsock

Note: This is for nonblocking sockets.

According to 
[MSDN's `select()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740141.aspx),
the `exceptfds` parameter can only monitor

- failed connection attempts via `connect()`
- Out of Band data

If I am not ever using OOB data, and the server never calls `connect()` to connect to anything, but only calls `accept()` for incoming connections, `send()` to send data to connections, and `recv()` to read data from connections, should the server therefore never monitor for exceptions when calling `select()`?

I was advised to still monitor for exceptions via `exceptfds` when `select()`'ing, but it looks like there is nothing that could possible cause an exception, according to the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Your document doesn't say anything of the sort. What it actually says is 'The parameter `exceptfds` identifies the sockets that are to be checked for the presence of OOB data or any exceptional error conditions.' It then goes on to discuss OOB and `connect()`, but nowhere does it say they are the only cases.

Comment: It discusses connect as if it is the only exceptional error condition since the documentation does not mention that any other exceptional errors exist. It goes as far as to say "This document does not define which other errors will be included." which makes it unclear if there are other errors to check for in WinSock and what they would be.

Comment: You are just wilfully misreading all this. 'Doesn't define which other errors will be included' **does not mean** 'no other errors are included', and no amount of word-twisting is going to make it so.

Comment: Can you give an example for Winsock of an error that could occur other than on connect?

Comment: No I can't, because Microsfot carefully didn't define them.

Comment: IOW, they may be defined in the future, or they may be defined by non-Microsoft socket providers. It is generally a good idea to monitor `exceptfds`. You can use `getsockopt(SO_ERROR)` to get the actual error code from a socket that is in an exceptional state.

Comment: Great answer Remy Lebeau. Wish I could mark this as answered but since you had posted it as a comment it will not let me.